# Can 2 or more attribute sets be applied to a magento configurable product?

Tags: magento, attributes, product, configurable

I'm trying to set up some products on our new magento store.
I need to have both colour and size as a choice for a lot of the products although these differ depending on the products e.g. T-shirt in blue, red and yellow in sizes from 2yrs to 13yrs.
I want to apply 2 attribute sets to a new configurable product but when I test it it doesn't come up. Plus on the associated products page the simple quick product creation doesn't come up.
I've got all the products set up as simple products but not with the attributes of colour and size.

Comment: You need to setup a single attribute set with all the attributes you need, you can actually have two attributes as super attributes (the ones used to group the simple products) it's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

for that you need only one Attribute Set and two product attributes . Attribute sets are for different product types for an example your store has both T-Shirts and Jeans we will need two separate attribute sets for T-Shirts and Jeans but to describe color and size of T-Shirt you will need  two product attributes associate to T-Shirts Attribute set . Refer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J06JAyf3gs) it will explain all